# Check for non empty array using Rails 4+ and PostgreSQL arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm referring to [this blog](http://blog.relatabase.com/rails-postgres-arrays) on how to use postgresql arrays in Rails 4. To be more precise, I'm using Rails 4.1.8.

I would like to enforce that the array should not be empty(should have at least one or more values) wrt the below table definition for the phones attribute.

Setting `null: false` as done below prevents me from doing a `Contacts.create(phones: nil)`, but `Contacts.create(phones: [])` saves to the database.

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.text :phones, array: true, null: false

    end
  end
end
```

What constraint can I use to ensure that `Contacts.create(phones: [])` raises an error saying that there should be at least one entry within the array?

Comment: Are you looking for an exception from the database when `phones` is empty or just an ActiveRecord validation?

Comment: Actually both, until you brought up this question. I don't know the difference between the two currently and when should what be chosen accordingly. I will research more on this.

Answer (score 3):

A regular presence validation should meet your requirement, since the empty array is not `present?`.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :phones, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Should be, `validates :phones, presence: true`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a [serialized attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) instead.

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.text :phones, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And in your model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :phones
  validate :phones, presence: true
  before_validation :clean_empty_array

  private

  def clean_empty_array
    self.phones = phones.presence
  end
end
```

Note that I added a `before_validation` cleaning method, to turn empty arrays into `nil` using `presence` (`[].presence => nil; ["1"].presence => ["1"])`. As an alternative, you could use [`attribute_normalizer`](https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer) gem to handle this kind of data normalization if you have this requirement in more places of your application.

---

*EDIT*: after discussion in the comments, `serialize` seems to be not the best way to go, since it carries important caveats such as querying issues. Thanks to @muistooshort for pointing these out. Also, the `before_validation` is not needed, since a `presence: true` validation is equivalent to what was proposed in the before_validation.

So the final solution to the question would involve keeping Postgresql array support and just validating against `phones` presence.

In short: keep `array: true` in your migration file and add this validation to your model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :phones, presence: true
end
```

Comment: I now realise why your answer is actually a better way to go instead using postgresql array support with rails4+ atleast from what I've seen so far and atleast for the above mentioned scenario. To be more precise, what I specifically observed was, if I'm storing an array of integers using the postgre sql array support like `[3,4]` and later on using them for comparison , I'm getting false, because it compares `["3","4"]` with `[3,4]` . With serialization, this doesn't happen. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help !! Using DB array field support is not really used in the community as far as I know.

Comment: The only thing is, I can't still do a check for the array to at least contain one element, I think this is because `[ ].nil?` in ruby returns false. I see that the record is still saving in the DB without throwing any error, given when a phones attribute is being assigned to an empty array.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion to use serialization of attributes as another way of doing things but I can't accept it as it doesn't meet the complete requirement of the question.

Comment: Yeah, let me complete that.

Comment: Please don't use `serialize`, it is a horrible ugly hack that throws opaque unqueryable data in your database. You can query inside an array but not inside a serialized column. If you're storing an array of integers then use a `int[]` in the database, not `text[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @muistooshort, I can see your point and agree `serialize` is not the best option for many cases, but I doubt on your total rejection or considering `serialize` as a *hack*. I can see many cases where this approach makes perfect sense: **a)** this approach would be perfectly OK if you don't need querying on the data (which perfectly may be the case), **b)** when you only need exact queries: you can use something like this `where(phones: [0100555, 0105556].to_yaml)`

Comment: Anyway @muistooshort, I'd love to see alternative approaches to this using the native DB capabilities.

Comment: A standard `presence: true` (which AFAIK calls `blank?`) should work as far as (Rails) validations go. If you want the database to raise an exception then you'd need to manually add a CHECK constraint; I'd do both because data validity and integrity logic really does belong inside the database. I stand by `serialize` being an ugly hack: it is quick and easy but almost always a big mistake that will make you suffer. Checking equality of YAML-strings can be problematic if the YAML encoder decides to change quotes, spacing, UTF-8 encoding, ... (these changes do happen over time).

Comment: PS: did you intentionally use octal numbers in your `to_yaml` example or are you just missing some quotes?

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't know that the data would be unqueryable. I'm thinking in long term, there generally would be querying to majority of the apps and I would like to have data which is queryable. The data that I'm using sometimes corresponds text like this `["D","B","C"]` or sometimes it could be integers too like `[1,3]`. Can you kindly suggest what can be best done in this scenario?

Comment: I will stick with array and text for now, instead of using serializing for reasons mentioned in the above comment. Also, a string can also be used to represent numbers so using `["1","3"]` should be okay as long as I'm displaying them correctly when printed.

Comment: @dgilperez your logic does the trick even when I'm using postgresql array support :), but I would request you to update the answer to use postgresql support(as the same was used in my original question) instead of using serialized attribute for reasons discussed in the comments above. I think majority of the times one wouldn't consider using a serialized attribute given that one can't query such data.

Comment: @muistooshort missing quotes ;) and yes, I also think `serialize` almost always means pain and suffering. Just out of curiosity, even when I think I know the answer: do you stand for completely removing `serialize` from rails, or do you see any reason / use case that justifies keeping it?

Comment: @muistooshort also, you are right about `presence: true` calling `blank?`, what renders the `before_validation` useless (I should have seen that when I used `.presence` before validating for `presence: true` !!)

Comment: @boddhisattva what do you want me to add / remove from the question? If   it's the Psql support, I think that credit belongs to muistooshort ... new answer?

Comment: @dgilperez I was thinking based on the discussion we've had(in the above comments) so far it would be good if you could kindly replace serialize with postgresql array support in your answer. muistooshort suggested what should be used as a best practice at a high level which even I truly appreciate but credit needs to be given to you for specifically answering the actual question that I asked which was to check for non empty array. Thank you.

Comment: Good! There you go :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer that `serialize` didn't exist at all, it should be harder to make mistakes. Rails tends to have a far too lacsadaisical attitude towards databases for my tastes: broken code is temporary, broken data is often forever.

Comment: +1 for the use of *lacsadaisical* :) And thanks, I think I actually fully agree with you, I just didn't know why.

Comment: @muistooshort In my case, I have added a check constraint `null: false` (kindly find this in the question). What my current observation is, if I run the code without the `before_validation` logic, and if I have a test case which validates that the creation of a new contact record with phones attribute being an `[](empty array)`, that test case should raise an error, but it doesn't. Based on this, my understanding is in this case we would need the `before_validation` logic. I think this post has 2 many comments, let's move this into a discussion/chat if u'd like to before we are asked to stop.